# What are the real life uses of role based authentication control in a database?

Tags: mongodb, authentication, role, access-control

I am new to database management. I was going through the [mongodb docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) for Role Based Authentication Control. I have understood how it works, but I have a few questions.

How is it applied in real life scenarios? For example let's say I am running a blogging web app. How would I use Role Based Authentication Control to improve my database management?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group several privileges into one Role. It is simpler to grant roles rather than dealing with a [bunch of privileges](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/privilege-actions/).

In a multi-tier architecture this might be no so important. You may have a user `admin`, `backup`, `http` - that's it.

However, when your database is used by many (human) users distributed over several departments with different responsibilities then Roles make your life much easier.

You create (or use built-in) roles like `backup`, `clusterAdmin`, `developer`, `reporter`, `powerUser`, etc. and grant such roles to users. You would have serious security flaws if every user would get full admin privileges on entire database.